# Generating two independently seeded random number lists in C

Tags: c, random

My program has two different functions, both of which call random numbers. I'd like to by able to independently seed the random numbers called by each function, so that I could run the full program several times calling the same random numbers for one function and changing the random numbers called by the other one. Any insights?

Comment: Short of a 3rd-party PRNG I can't think of an algorithmic way to you can seed only partial calls using the same RNG. You may have to go outside the CRT for and acquire distinct prng presence such as from a crypto library (OpenSSL, RSA BSAFE, etc.).

Comment: You have to implement it yourself, unfortunately, as the C standard only have a single pseudo-random generator with a single seed. Or move to C++ which since C++11 have great [pseudo-random number facilities](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random).

Answer (score 2):

POSIX provides the [`drand48()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/drand48.html) family of functions; you can use some of those to achieve the effect you require:

- `double erand48(unsigned short xsubi[3]);`
- `long jrand48(unsigned short xsubi[3]);`
- `long nrand48(unsigned short xsubi[3]);`

Comment: SVID 3 declared those functions obsolete. `rand_r` should be used instead.

Comment: POSIX 2008 has no such 'obsolescent' declaration for `drand48()` et al, and it is more recent than SVID 3.  Further, it documents [`rand_r()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/rand_r.html) but marks it `OB_CX` (obsolescent C extension).

Answer (score 0):

You could seed the first one with some constant, and the second one with the current time

Comment: You're somewhat missing his point. The C runtime has ***a*** (singular) prng. Consequently, seeding one seeds **the one**.

Answer (score 0):

In an object oriented language, you'd create two independent random number generator objects and call them separately. In C, you'll have to do that work yourself. Grab some code like [Mersenne Twister](http://www.math.sci.hiroshima-u.ac.jp/~m-mat/MT/emt.html), or my [onejoker](https://github.com/lcrocker/onejoker/src/clib/prng.c), and modify it to take multiple state variables. For example, the JKISS prng in my code keeps its internal state in four variables x, y, z, and c. Change those to arrays, or an array of structures, and keep several sets. Then seed each one independently. So wherever there's currently an "x" in the code, change it to "x[i]", where i is the number of the stream. Now that you mention it, it might not be a bad idea for me to do that... :)

Comment: FYI, TinyMT already uses a structure for its internal state, so you might be able to use that right out of the box.